# Is it possible to create a Maxwell demon where entropy doesn't get stored in the brain of the "demon"?

Tags: science-based, thermodynamics

So say for example in a hypothetical world where someone wants to extract energy but the temperature is in perfect equilibrium and they have no way of getting a thermal difference but there is a a ton of energy still in the system.

So say there is a maxwell demon setup where the hotter particles are seperated from the cold particles, but instead of it happening due to some kind of thinking process which would cause energy to be used once deleting the information stored in memory, what if the hotter particles just cause the device to experience slightly more force in one side which causes the mechanical aspect of the device to open and allow the faster particle in and traps it, and repeats until all the hotter particles are on one side and colder particles are on other side but in this version no one or no computer tried to remember all the particle motion. So no energy would be used in removing memory outside of maybe the memory capacity needed to build such a system in the first place.

So this device would essentially extract energy from a really hot planet which isn't in thermal equilibrium and is the size of 1 football field and used to beat the second law of thermodynamics? Is this possible or is there any problems with this?

Comment: You mean like how high-energy atoms leave the Earth's atmosphere and no one remembers each one?

Comment: This sounds almost like a physics question, particularly the part where you say "used to beat the second law of thermodynamics ... Is this possible?" I'm willing to lay a large bet that a physicist will say "no" to that.

Comment: Actually, isn't this just restating Maxwell's original thought experiment? The original "demon" is just examining each molecule as it passes, like your "mechanical aspect". The idea of "memory" only comes in as an attempt to counter proofs that "examining" each molecule (or, in your wording, "experiencing force") requires energy.

Comment: But experiencing force only needs temporary energy, because Work=Force*Displacement so even if there is some energy needed to move the door because of the above equation, the energy can be reclaimed as the door is closing because the initial kinetic energy of the door and final kinetic energy will be the same. So net Work or energy used is zero and since there is no memory, there is also no heating needed to delete the information from someone's memory